# Error in getting a URL into my .bib file using Texworks

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, errors, texworks

When trying to get my .bib file into my .tex i get this error message.

```
You're missing a field part---line 52 of file Bib.bib
 :  howpublished = 
 :            "{\url{https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15859-f11/www/notes/lecture05.pdf}}"     
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
```

In my .tex file i start my bibliogrphy as follows:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Bib}
```

My .bib file for this url with the error message is as follows:

```
@misc{10,
author = "Anupam Gupta",
title = "Linear Programming Duality",
howpublished = "{\url{https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15859-f11/www/notes/lecture05.pdf}}"
}
```

My preamble is large but it is as follow:

```
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including graphics (via \includegraphics).
\usepackage{amsmath}  % Improves typographic quality of mathematical output.
\usepackage{amsfonts} % For mathematical fonts.
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsthm} % Needed to typeset theorem environments.
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk} % Needed for author and affiliation.
\usepackage{amsopn} % Allows the declaration of new mathematical operators.
\usepackage{amssymb} % Extended set of mathematical symbols.
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % Raph Smith's mathematical script font.
\usepackage{booktabs} % Improves the typographical quality of tables.
\usepackage{natbib} % Citations and bibliography.
\usepackage{tikz} % Extends the figure generation capabilities of LaTeX.
\usepackage{algorithm} % Necessary for including algorithmic structures.
\usepackage{float} % Allows the creation of own floating environments.
\usepackage{caption} % Allows the customisation of captions.
\usepackage{abstract} % For including abstracts in documents.
\usepackage{listings} % For the inclusion of source code.
\usepackage{color} % Used for colour commands.
\usepackage{pgfplots} %extends tikz functionality
\usepackage{hyperref,lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[scale=0.8,vmarginratio={1:2},heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
```

Comment: I'm just guessing, but the `howpublished` entry is delimited by two single quotes (`''`). But usually the delimiter is one double quote (`"`). Change to double quotes to see what happens.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can also use braces instead of `"` (which TeXworks has the bad habit to change into `''`).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik - you should post your comment as an answer. :-)

Comment: It was a mistype when i posted the question. Thanks for the quick response and input though!

Comment: Off-topic: The `hyperref` package should be loaded last. Also: no need to load the `tikz` package -- or any other package... _ twice.

Comment: @Mico Done :). I'm not at the computer, so I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the delimiter of the `howpublished` field.

The valid separators for bibtex files are double quotes (`" "`) and curly braces (`{ }`).

The file you posted is using a pair of single quotes (`'' ''`) and this is breaking bibtex.

Change your entry to either:

```
@misc{10,
author = "Anupam Gupta",
title = "Linear Programming Duality",
howpublished = "\url{https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15859-f11/www/notes/lecture05.pdf}"
}
```

or

```
@misc{10,
author = "Anupam Gupta",
title = "Linear Programming Duality",
howpublished = {\url{https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15859-f11/www/notes/lecture05.pdf}}
}
```

and it will work.

(make sure you delete the .aux and .bbl files to force texmaker run bibtex again :)